# JMeter's JVM crashes after 10 minutes

Tags: java, jmeter, crash, jvm-crash

I'm using JMeter with 10 slaves. After executing for 10 minutes java crashes:

---

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000051c39ea0, pid=2488, tid=0x0000000000000ac0
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x69ea0]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\hs_err_pid2488.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

---

```
VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms512m -Xmx3276m -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
java_command: ApacheJMeter.jar
java_class_path (initial): ApacheJMeter.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\
USERNAME=XXX
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
```

---

I recently had to increase Java heap size for all the slaves and server machine due to OutOfMemoryError.
all 10 slaves has 4GM RAM and server machine has 16GM RAM.
Current JMeter settings are : **HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx3276m**

Comment: On what machine are the slaves installed ? 10 different machines or only 1 machine ? what is the memory of each slave machine ?

Comment: @ UBIK LOAD PACK 10 different machines and each machine has 4GB of RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with Java 8, but still using an old JMeter 3.1 version,

Please try to use latest [Version 5.0](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) which is the first listed in JMeter [best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), and also for your issue, reduce as much resources as possible:

> - Use non-GUI mode: jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl
> - Use as few Listeners as possible; if using the -l flag as above they can all be deleted or disabled.
> - Don't use "View Results Tree" or "View Results in Table" listeners during the load test, use them only during scripting phase to debug your scripts.
> - Rather than using lots of similar samplers, use the same sampler in a loop, and use variables (CSV Data Set) to vary the sample. [The Include Controller does not help here, as it adds all the test elements in the file to the test plan.]
> - Don't use functional mode
> - Use CSV output rather than XML
> - Only save the data that you need
> - Use as few Assertions as possible
>     Use the most performing scripting language (see JSR223 section)

Comment: Yes, It's an old setup of JMeter and I updated to Java 8 x64 just so that I could get heap size greater than 1GB. I don't really want to mess with the setup if possible as slaves are all on linux system and If I update to JMeter 5.0 I'll have to update all the slaves too.

Comment: I'm only using [Summary report] and no other listeners at all.

Comment: @VishwasTrivedi Summary report is also a listener, try to remove it, can you disable assertion(s) also? also can you show relevant code error in dmp file?

Comment: I need some kind of report to determine the failure rate of the requests that is why I'm, using Summary Report. Assertion is already disabled. I believe that this problem occurs because I'm executing it with LoopCount forever. Thought right now I'm trying from non-GUI mode as you suggested.

Comment: I have 10 slaves and 5 threads per slave. Which I believe creates high load(this should not happen though).

Comment: @VishwasTrivedi it'll help if you download latest version (to all slaves) and try it, because there were performance improvements, e.g. https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62426

Answer (score 1):

It's not a crash of JMeter, but a JVM crash.

Your configuration has many issues:

You have this:

> -Xms512m -Xmx3276m -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m

Remove those as your tuning is wrong:

> -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m

Also check if you are running the 10 slaves on same machine that:

> (heap+metaspace size + Number of threads x Stack size) x 10 + 300m < Machine memory size

You say you have 5 threads per slave , why use distributed testing for such low number of slaves ? JMeter is capable of running 1000 threads without problems on 1 average machine.

Finally, upgrade your jmeter very old version.

Comment: I am running slaves on different machines. In my testing scenario I need to gradually increase the number of threads(number of users) to check the performance. Also I don't need to go upto 1000 threads anyhow as current server is not designed for that much load.

Comment: are you telling me to remove -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m from settings?

Comment: okay, but if I execute from command line there are no error or warnings.

Comment: Yes, there will not be immediately an error. Did you try what I advise ?

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting for the current execution to finish to check the result of solution suggested by @ user7294900.

Comment: what did you change exactly ?

Comment: what fixed your problem exactly ?

Comment: Implemented first 3 points suggested by user7294900.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603807/6759485